# Prove this inequality using laplace transform

Tags: inequality, laplace-transform

Let $n$ be a strictly positive integer, and $a_1,\cdots a_n,b_1,b_2 \cdots b_n$ strictly positive real numbers.

Prove that
$$\sum_{i=1}^n (\frac{a_i}{b_i})^2 \le 2\sum_{1\le j,i \le n} \frac{a_ia_j}{(b_i+b_j)^2}+k\sqrt{\sum_{1\le j,i \le n} \frac{a_ia_j}{(b_i+b_j)} \sum_{1\le j,i \le n} \frac{a_ia_j}{(b_i+b_j)^3}}    $$
for a certain $k$ which we need to determine.
I just need hints, I don't want the answer.

Comment: 1) What have you tried yet ? 2) The connection with Laplace Transform is non evident. Could you explain it. It might help...

Comment: using laplace i couldn't reach any where.
i dont know what is the conncetion.
i tried to write the sums of the second side using the first one in the first side to solve equation i thought it would be of second degree